# angular.forEach leads to The controller with the name 'TodoListController' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, webpack, twig

I'm trying to use AngularJS with PHP / Symfony / Webpack / Twig (I'm very new in each of them). First, I'm trying to make the "todo list" example on AngularJS webpage work.

I get the following error "The controller with the name 'TodoListController' is not registered", but, curiously, as soon as I comment the calls to angular.forEach in the code below, it works.

I precise that the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635776/angularjs-controller-is-not-registered) didn't help me.

**EDIT:** The problem doesn't seem to be linked to Angular.forEach; indeed I have exactly the same behavior with JavaScript forEach.

**base.html.twig**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
       {% block stylesheets %}
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('./build/app.css') }}">
       {% endblock %}
   </head>
   <body>
       {% block body %}{% endblock %}
       {% block javascripts %}
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.js"></script>
           <script src="{{ asset('./build/app.js') }}"></script>
           <script src="{{ asset('./build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
           <script src="{{ asset('./build/todo.js') }}"></script>
       {% endblock %}
   </body>
</html>
```

**default.html.twig:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

   <div>
     <h1>1er exemple</h1>
     <label>Name:</label>
     <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
     <hr>
     <h2>Hello {[{ yourName }]}!</h2>
   </div>   

   ============================================

   <h1>2eme exemple</h1>
   <h2>Todo</h2>
   <div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
     <span>{[{ todoList.remaining() }]} of {[{ todoList.todos.length }]} remaining</span>
     [ <a href="" ng-click="todoList.archive()">archive</a> ]
     <ul class="unstyled">
       <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
         <label class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
           <span class="done-{[{todo.done}}">{[{ todo.text }]}</span>
         </label>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo()">
       <input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText"  size="30"
              placeholder="add new todo here">
       <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
     </form>
   </div>

{% endblock %}
```

**todo.js**:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('TodoListController', mafonction);

function mafonction(){
    var todoList = this;
    todoList.todos = [
      {text:'learn AngularJS', done:true},
      {text:'build an AngularJS app', done:false}];

      todoList.addTodo = function() {
        todoList.todos.push({text:todoList.todoText, done:false});
        todoList.todoText = '';
      };

      todoList.remaining = function() {
        var count = 0;

        angular.forEach(todoList.todos, function(todo) {
          count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
        });
        return count;
      };

      todoList.archive = function() {
        var oldTodos = todoList.todos;
        todoList.todos = [];
        angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
          if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
        });
      };
};
```

**app.js**

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

 // any CSS you require will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
require('../css/app.css');

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
// const $ = require('jquery');

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function($interpolateProvider){
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
console.log("Start End Symbole");
```

Comment: where is the main module? what is inside app.js?

Comment: Sorry, I just added app.js. What do you mean by "main module"? If I understand well, I have just one module called "app".

Comment: What is the error message in the Developer Console?

Comment: `angular.js:15567 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'TodoListController' is not registered.`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that the code copy the array:

```
  todoList.archive = function() {
    ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶o̶l̶d̶T̶o̶d̶o̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶t̶o̶d̶o̶L̶i̶s̶t̶.̶t̶o̶d̶o̶s̶;̶
    var oldTodos = angular.copy(todoList.todos);
    todoList.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
      if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
```

JavaScript is a share-by-reference language. The assignment operator does not create a new array. Instead it references the same array in memory.

---

## Update

I also recommend the app uses the same version of ngRoute as the AngularJS library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>
̶<̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶ ̶s̶r̶c̶=̶"̶h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶/̶/̶a̶j̶a̶x̶.̶g̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶a̶p̶i̶s̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶a̶j̶a̶x̶/̶l̶i̶b̶s̶/̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶j̶s̶/̶1̶.̶2̶.̶0̶r̶c̶1̶/̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶-̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶.̶j̶s̶"̶>̶<̶/̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶>̶ ̶
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```